# how to play audio as background in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, audio-player

I have created `Player` object as

```
player = Manager.createPlayer(inputStream,"audio/mpeg");
```

and plays the audio as

```
player.realize(); player.prefetch(); player.start();
```

It starts playing the stream. Here the `inputstream` refers live streaming url. Now my question is when i click on the back button the application will be closed so that player also will stop the playing. but I need to play the audio in background even the application is closed and after launching the app i dont want to initialize the `Player` object again,for this i have to maintain the `Player` object as singleton. I am using 4.7 blackberry api.Can someone please tell me how all these will possible?

thanks
venu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the "onClose()" method in your Screen class to catch the close event and put your app in the background:

```
public boolean onClose() {
    Application.getApplication().requestBackground();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. It almost solved my problem. But one thing we need to consider. If i place the above code snippet, my app will always go to background.it is to be in background when the player is running otherwise it should be removed from stack. can you please tell me how can i alter onclose() method?

Comment: for this i have altered onClose() as public boolean onClose() {
  if(player.getState()==Player.STARTED){
      Application.getApplication().requestBackground();
      return false;
  }
  return true;
 }  but it will never allow me to close the application.

Comment: Looks like maybe the player state is always Player.STARTED.  Make sure you call Player.stop() and/or Player.close() when you don't want the media to play which will move the player state out of Player.STARTED.

Comment: I got what i wanted by using close() method as if(player!=null&&player.getState()==Player.STARTED){      Application.getApplication().requestBackground();
   }else{
    super.close();
   }

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the multi-part blog post by Tim Windsor from RIM on running applications in the background.

- [Part 1](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/06/super-apps-java-series-running-in-the-background-part-1/)
- [Part 2](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/06/running-in-the-background-part-2/)
- [Part 3](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/07/running-in-the-background-part-three/)
- [Part 4](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/09/running-in-the-background-part-4/)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to override the behaviour of the back button and just send your app to background without closing it.Then the player will continue to play. There are many resources and tutorials on this. Maybe something from the links @Ted Hopp posted might help you.